# PMD or Checkstyle check to prohibit usage of certain classes

Tags: java, checkstyle, pmd

Is there any PMD or Checkstyle rule available that could help me to prohibit usage of some certain classes in Java code?

In my case I'd like to ban all of the following in all possible contexts:

- `org.apache.commons.lang3.CharEncoding`
- `org.apache.commons.lang.CharEncoding`
- `org.apache.commons.codec.CharEncoding`

I've found [IllegalImport](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html#IllegalImport) check, but it's about packages, not particular classes.

Comment: Perhaps this can help you ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416870/checkstyle-rule-to-prevent-invocation-of-some-methods-and-constructors

Comment: @EmAe but the above is about certain methods or constructors, while my question is about classes

Comment: I know but what i was pointing at that I am not aware of any such restrictions so perhaps you might have to write something on your own just the way this post hints for writing on your own for methods.

Comment: @EmAe sure, if there is nothing ready to use I'm gonna write my own check

Comment: I don't speak xml, but look at this `checkstyle/config/import-control.xml` at https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/config/import-control.xml

Comment: Interesting that you would ask us, when it is you personally who develops Checkstyle ... You are #3 contributor (which is great)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PMD you can write rule like this:

```
<rule name="Prohibited classes"
      language="java"
      message="Avoid using these classes."
      class="net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.rule.XPathRule" >
    <description>
        Avoid using these classes, there are better alternatives.
    </description>
    <priority>3</priority>
    <properties>
        <property name="xpath">
            <value>
                <![CDATA[
//Name[pmd-java:typeIs('org.apache.commons.lang3.CharEncoding')] |
//Name[pmd-java:typeIs('org.apache.commons.lang.CharEncoding')] |
//Name[pmd-java:typeIs('org.apache.commons.codec.CharEncoding')]
]]>
            </value>
        </property>
    </properties>
</rule>
```

Or `//Name[starts-with(@Image, 'com.sun.')]` to prohibit package import.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use these pmd extensions to blacklist classes and methods: https://github.com/LiveRamp/pmd_extensions